# How to create a dropdown list that contains distinct Text in option

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, selectlist

I'm fetching a list of elements from database:

```
ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(db.UserRegister, "Id", "SystemCode");
```

and the view :

```
@Html.DropDownList("Id", null })
```

The result of dropdown I'm getting is :

```
Value | Text
  1   | James
  2   | James
  3   | John
```

What I want is :

```
Value | Text
  1   | James
  3   | John
```

The Value of the above Text `James` could be `1` or `2`, doesn't matter, the text I'll get will always be `James`

How do I create a drop down that contains distinct `Text` as shown above?

Any help will be deeply appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: If the value of the ID does not matter, then including the ID is meaningless so you might as well just do `var names = db.YourTable.Select(x => x.Text).Distinct(); ViewBag.Id = new SelectList(names);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Value of Id doesn't matter in a sense that `James` belongs to only `1` and `2` and not `3`, therefore, it doesn't matter that the value of `James` is either `1` or `2`, but it definitely needs to be one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You linq query needs to perform a GroupBy.

```
db.UserRegister.GroupBy(x => x.SystemCode)
                    .Select(g => new SelectListItem {Value = g.Min(w => w.Id), Text = g.Key})
                    .ToList();
```

I'd then change you view to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Id, ViewBag.Id);
```